# Order of a prime field

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I need some help with proving some statements.

I know that a $2\times 2$ matrix is not invertible if and only if one row is a multiple of the other. **How can the forward direction be proven, given that $ad$ is not equal to $bc$?**

Also, given $F_p$ is a prime field, let $V={F_p}^2$. I need to prove that the number of bases of $V$ is equal to $p(p+1)(p-1)^2$? I already know how to prove that the order of the general linear group $GL_2(F_p)$ is equal to the number of bases of $V$.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If $A$ is invertible, then $A^t$ is invertible, and hence the $\{$columns of $A^t\}$ = $\{A^te_i\}$, where $\{e_i\}$ is a basis for your vector space, form a linearly independent set. Hence, the rows of $A$ form a linearly independent set. In particular, they cannot be multiples of each other.
2. As you say, you are trying to find the order of $GL_2(F_p)$ : Count the number of possible entries in the $2\times 2$ matrix. The row can have any 2 entries, as long as either one of them is non-zero. Hence you have $p^2 - 1$ choices. The second row can be anything except a multiple of the first row. There are $p$ such multiples, so this gives $p^2 - p$ choices. Hence,
   $$
   |GL_2(F_p)| = (p^2-1)(p^2-p)
   $$

Comment: Thanks, but what about the order of $V={F_p}^2$?

Comment: I don't understand. Are you asking about the number of bases of $V$ or about the order of $V$ (which is just $p^2$)

Comment: Sorry, I was asking about the number of bases of $V$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that for the first part, if $ad\neq bc$ then we can take the reciprocal of the determinant, and therefore explicitly define the inverse in the usual way.

$\frac 1{ad-bc}\left(\begin{matrix}
  d & -b \\
  -c & a 
 \end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}
  a & b \\
  c & d 
 \end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}
  1 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 
 \end{matrix}\right)$

Suppose $a=kc$ and $b=kd$ so that the first row is a multiple of the second, then we have $ad=kcd=ckd=cb$. The only missing case is if the second row is zero, in which case it is trivial that $ad=bc$.